# Use twisted SSL4ClientEndpoint without verify the server certificate

Tags: python-3.x, twisted

Is there any way to use twisted SSL4ClientEndpoint without the need of verifying the server cert?
(or without using optionsForClientTLS)

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, i just used ssl.CertificateOptions instead of optionsForClientTLS with parameter 'verify' equal to False and it worked:

```
options = ssl.CertificateOptions(
    verify = False,
    acceptableProtocols=[b'h2'],
)
```